# How to do Plain Select

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Autodesk Forge Viewer with the Edit2D tools to allow the user to draw and modify polygons.  I have this working with the polygonTool and polyEditTool.  However, I also have a use case where the user needs to be able to select polygons but NOT make any modifications.  As far as I can tell, the polyEditTool and moveTool allow the user to select polygons but they also allow them to modify.  If I deactivate all tools they can't select, and the standard viewer selection doesn't seem to allow you to select the Edit2D shapes.

How can I get a selection only mode?

Answer (score 1):

The Edit2D extension does not have any built-in option to only enable selection but not editing of shapes, and the workaround you suggested earlier looks reasonable.

Another option to consider would be implementing a custom subclass of `EditToolBase` (you could use the [implementation of the official Edit2D tools](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Edit2D/Edit2D.js) as a reference) that would only allow selection, and nothing else.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will look into the implementation and `EditToolBase` but good to know the workaround found is a decent method for the time being.  Would be a nice tool to add to Edit2D if there is a place to put in a request...

Answer (score 0):

Ok well it seems a little convoluted but I found a way that seems to work.  The move tool allows you to select and move, but each shape has a `movable` property.  If you set `movable` to false on the shape it can still be selected but can't be moved.  So if you are switching between the editing and selection only modes you would have to change that property by iterating over the shapes on the layer and set it each time.  Here is my implementation:

```
for (const shape of state.editor.defaultContext.layer.shapes) {
  // @ts-ignore
  shape.movable = tool !== DrawTools.Select;
}
```

Note that TypeScript definitions don't seem to include the `movable` property so I have to ignore the error.

This seems to work but if there is a better solution out there I would be happy to accept a better answer.